# Use "date_views_filter_handler" filter handler for custom table field

Tags: views

How can I use "date_views_filter_handler" defined in date module as filter handler for a column of integer type on custom table while exposing it to views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not say this answer the question I asked but must say this answer worked the way I want.

Instead of using "date_views_filter_handler" I used "date_views_filter_handler_simple" and it just worked like a charm.Here is what I did while exposing my custom table to views.

```
  $data['jh_report']['date_of_purchase'] = array(
    'title' => t('Date of purchase'),
    'help' => t('Date of last purchase for current month'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'date_views_filter_handler_simple',
    ),
  );
```